# setTimeout executing synchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm new to Javascript and trying to understand async programming. So I wrote the below code in chrome developer tools workspace -

```
console.log("hi1");
setTimeout(console.log("hi-async"),1000);
console.log("hi3");
```

The out put I was expecting was -

```
hi1
hi3
hi-async
```

Instead, the console printed following, without the 1 second delay (all at once) -

```
hi1
hi-async
hi3
```

So basically, the setTimeout function was executed synchronously! Can someone tell me why that's the case? I thought setTimeout is an async function and will always be executed asynchronously. Am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You are calling `console.log()` and passing its return result as the first argument to `setTimeout()` (which is `undefined`). The `setTimeout()` method should be passed a function that it will execute

Comment: `setTimeout` expects an callback function and the time. You pass `undefined` and time. If you execute `console.log()` it returns undefined

Comment: Just to clarify what the above commentors mean, all you need to do is change your call to setTimeout to: setTimeout(() => console.log("hi-async"),1000);